# warning message and notice when trying to use fuction to call sql query

Tags: php, mysql, function, warnings

once the function is called I get a warning saying Illegal string offset 'unitname' and a notice saying Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0

```
    $unitname = "";

    function display($unitname) {
    $unitname = "";

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT unitname from UNIT";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br>Unit Name:" . $unitname["unitname"] . "<br>";
        }
      } else {
    echo "0 results";
   }
    return $unitname;
   }

  ?>
```

Comment: Creating a new connection for each function call isn't very practical, you should pass it as an argument to the function instead

Comment: What sense does it make to empty $unitname as you use that variable as a parameter too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using $row to fetch the results of your SQL into and you were using $unitname to display the results...

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br>Unit Name:" . $row["unitname"] . "<br>";
}
```

You should use `$row` each time.

Not entirely sure what you want to return, is it the one unit name - or do you want a list of them?

Comment: Could you explain this further

Comment: I've updated the answer, but the fetch_assoc() returns the results of the query into $row, you where trying to use $unitname to display these results.